# What is type of these expression?

Tags: types, scheme, expression

Can you help me to indicate the type the following expressions?

If the expression defines a procedure, then indicate the type of the procedure so defined. For unkown type, it can be used A,B,C,etc

I couldn't do it, so I hope there is anyone who can explain me.

1) `(lambda (p) (+ 1 (p 3)))`

2) `(lambda (x y comp) (if (comp x y) (+ x 1) (+ y 1)))`

Comment: Start with what you know (for instance, if you have `(+ 5 a)`, `a` must be a number) and "fill in the blanks".

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the first example:

    `(lambda (p) (+ 1 (p 3)))`

We know that the plus has the type + : Number Number -> Number.  From here, we can deduce a few things.  If p takes in 3, a Number, we can determine that it's input type is Number.  So far we know p : Number -> ????.  Next we can look at where the value of (p 3) goes.  This data is immediately used in +.  We already know that the type of plus is + : Number Number -> Number.  We then know that the output of (p 3) must also be a number.  Therefore we know that p : Number -> Number.  This means that the whole lambda has the type (Number -> Number) -> Number.

In the second example,

    `(lambda (x y comp) (if (comp x y) (+ x 1) (+ y 1)))`

We know that x and y must be of type Number, because they are used by plus.  From here, we also know that the output of comp must be a boolean, as it is used in an if expression (in most if not all Schemes, any non false value is considered true in an if statement, so it is possible that comp could return any type).  Finally, we know that comp takes both x and y, which are both Numbers so the type of comp must be Number Number -> Boolean.  That makes the type of the lambda Number Number (Number Number -> Boolean) -> Number.